# Laravel angularjs configuration

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I try to include Angularjs in Laravel but i don't know what mistake i made i got error

**Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'**

**myHead.blad.php**

```
<title>Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/homeController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/aboutController.js"></script>
```

**myWelcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <?php echo View::make('layouts/head'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php echo View::make('layouts/header'); ?>  

        <div  ng-controller="HelloController">Hi {{name}} welcome to AngularJS Tutorial Series</div>
        <button class="btn" name="test" value="test">Test</button>
    </body>

    <?php echo View::make('layouts/footer'); ?>  
</html>
```

**Hellocontroller.js**

```
MyApp.controller('HelloController', hello);

function hello($scope)
{
    $scope.name = "Test";
}
```

Please tell me how to configure **Angularjs** in **Laravel**

Comment: you don't have `var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])`?

Comment: I declare that also in public/app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interpolated expression need to change if you want to work with laravel because laravel and angular js both use same {{}} interpolation symbol for expression exicuition

Add the code where you define your app

```
 var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    MyApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
     });
```

myWelcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <?php echo View::make('layouts/head'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php echo View::make('layouts/header'); ?>  

        <div  ng-controller="HelloController">Hi <%name%> welcome to AngularJS Tutorial Series</div>
        <button class="btn" name="test" value="test">Test</button>
    </body>

    <?php echo View::make('layouts/footer'); ?>  
</html>
```

Comment: it print this Hi <%name%> welcome to AngularJS Tutorial Series

Comment: have you set the interpolateprovider.startSymbol or interpolateprovider.endSymbol config code inside the app.js ?

Comment: Thanks it's working can you please explain what is the reason

Comment: The Reason is :  laravel and angular js both use same {{}} interpolation symbol for expression exicuition that wht it's showing error

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check into your code the issue persist with injection due to which your code was not working, it's working with your code, please have a look

```
(function(angular) {
```

'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'Test';

});
})(window.angular);

https://plnkr.co/edit/30nM20o7MHrxPifVu9Ig?p=preview